# How can I get the parent key of an entity when I only know its id?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, key, google-cloud-datastore

I have the id of an child, and would like to get the parent Entity without looping through all entities.

I can not create the Key with KeyFactory.createKey, because I don't know the parent, and I can not use a filter on the Id, as I can not create a Key.

An example might clarify:
- Entity Supplier
- Entity Product, which has a Supplier as Parent.

How do I find the Supplier if I know the id (Key.getId()) of a product? What am I missing?

Comment: You're not being clear, the question states you know the id of the ancestor, and your last sentence says that you know the id of a product, which is it?

Comment: is this really related with entity-framework ?

Comment: Sorry, I know the id of the Child, and want to get the Parent Entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't, the `id` by itself is not enough information because that's relative to its parent; take for example the following keys:

```
Key('Supplier', 1, 'Product', 1)
Key('Supplier', 2, 'Product', 1)
Key('Supplier', 1, 'Product', 2)
```

These are three unique products, but as you can see, only knowing that you're looking for `Product.id == 1` is not nearly enought to find the right one.

This situation doesn't really have a good solution, besides what you already figured (and ruled out) about looping through them all, and even then there might be multiple suppliers (as proven by my conveniently crafted example).

So you'll need a better design :) always keep in mind that in a parent/child relationship, the **only** valid key is a full key.

Comment: Thanks. However, the Product id is unique, and one Product always belongs to one Supplier in this case. Probably using parent will not work, anyway, so I will probably go with Query based on a supplierId property in the Product entity

Comment: I am not assigning it manually, the idea was/is to use the getKet().getId()

Comment: If they're assigned by the datastore then they are only unique in relation to their parent, it's like if each parent creates a new namespace. If you come from SQL I understand you're used to only keep track of the id, but in this case you need to use the complete key, so instead of `getId` use `KeyFactory.keyToString` and then `KeyFactory.stringToKey`.

Comment: Thanks, will try that. I do come from SQL, or probably I still have two legs and an arm there :-)